# Weird BOOT_COMPLETED behavior

Tags: android

I was expecting my app to load the BroadcastReceiver AutoStartOnBoot when I reboot my device.

1. I uninstall and install the app. Which means that all existing settings are deleted. I then power down the phone. And power it back up, the Broadcast receiver is never called.
2. I now, power down the device one more time and power it up again. Yet, broadcast receiver is not called.
3. I now launch the app once. Clear data. And power it down. I power it up. Now, the broadcast receiver is called.

Manifest

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".AutoStartOnBoot"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I have the permission setup

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246326/how-to-receiving-broadcast-when-application-installed-or-removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All answers are correct. This behavior is as per expectation. The app is inactive when installed, until its manually launched by the owner. Only after that is the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast receiver registered to the OS.

Unless we put the app in the system folder, which keeps all apps in `active` state. We are device company, `adb push your.apk /system/app` is possible for us.

Some interesting links, [here](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/activating-applications/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531926/how-to-start-a-service-when-apk-is-installed-for-the-first-time)

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

From your First two Points

```
1.I uninstall and install the app. Which means that all existing settings are deleted. I then power down the phone. And power it back up, the Broadcast receiver is never called.
2.I now, power down the device one more time and power it up again. Yet, broadcast  receiver is not called.
```

Why it is not working??

Here your just installed the app but not launched.In android after first launch only all your manifest data is registered and all receivers work.But in your third case its working because you are launched the app so here all receivers gets registered.

For more check here [Broadcast Receiver not working immediately after package installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528892/broadcast-receiver-not-working-immediately-after-package-installation)

You have to add this permission outside of the `<application>` tag in manifest file

instead of this

```
<android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
```

Add this like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: I have it,   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

Comment: @Siddharth ok..what is this lines means "when I install the app for the first time?", is  it working for the next time??

Comment: clarified my question

Comment: It has something to do with the 3.1 security loop hole fix.

Comment: @Siddharth yes.if the loop not fixed you will get notified after your app  settings force stop also..that leads to be security issues.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior that you describe is perfectly normal. Something needs to use an explicit `Intent` to start up one of your components before your manifest-registered receivers will work. Typically, that will be the user tapping on your home screen launcher icon.

See [the Android 3.1 release notes](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols) for more about this.

Comment: I did not get anything related to boot onthis link.